# why does excludeFromRecents remove all activities?

Tags: android, android-intent

My app has two entry points (MainActivity and FromNotificationActivity).

I want MainActivity to appear in recent tasks, but not FromNotificationActivity)

With nothing declared in the manifest, if I do...

- MainActivity
- Back
- FromNotificationActivity
- Back

... I find FromNotificationActivity listed in recent tasks

If I add  `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` to FromNotificationActivity in the manifest and repeat the same sequence, I find **nothing** in the recent lists.

What incantations must I invoke such that after the above sequence of steps, I get MainActivity in the recent list.

Comment: Add **android:noHistory="true"**  to NotificationActivity. it  can do what you want

Answer (score 49, accepted):

By default, all the activities of an application have the same affinity. Activities with same affinity conceptually belong to the same task. Hence in this case both `MainActivity` and `FromNotificationActivity` belong to the same task. `android:excludeFromRecents` ensures the task is not listed in the recent apps. That is the reason, when `android:excludeFromRecents` is set to `true` for `FromNotificationActivity`,  `MainActivity` disappers from history.

**Solution:** 
Use `android:taskAffinity` to specify different tasks for both the activities. Use `android:excludeFromRecents` for `FromNotificationActivity` if that task should not be shown in history at all.

```
<activity   
    android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:taskAffinity=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity> 

<activity android:name="com.example.FromNotificationActivity"
    android:label="@string/notification_name"
    android:taskAffinity=".NotificationActivity"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: I think it can be acheived by adding  android:noHistory="true" to NotificationActivity in manifest

Comment: Why do you have 2 intent filters for launching?

Answer (score 7):

From [the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

> **android:excludeFromRecents**
>   *Whether or not the task initiated by this activity should be excluded from the list of recently used applications ("recent apps"). That is, when this activity is the root activity of a new task, this attribute determines whether the task should not appear in the list of recent apps. Set "true" if the task should be excluded from the list; set "false" if it should be included. The default value is "false".*

So it's not the activity, but the task what this flag controls. You didn't post the activity elements in your manifest, but my guess is that those two activities are running in the same task. Changing the launchMode to singleTask on both of them should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You should use intent flag from your First_Activity to Second_Activity.
No need to declare any thing in the manifest.
By using this code, the activity which'll go for intent, will be your recent activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CONTEXT_OF_CURRENT_ACTIVITY, YOUR_ACTIVITY.class);
intent.putExtra("NAME", "VALUE");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Hope it'll be useful..